# Positioning an item at the bottom of a fluid container

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my html / css. I want to have a "learn more" box in every one of my three sections, located at the bottom middle of each one.

http://jsfiddle.net/9uxGq/4/

CSS

```
#learn {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    z-index:1;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    left:50%;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: -75px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#learn a {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

It seems to work fine in the top box:
`<div id="learn"><a href="#">Learn More</a>`

However in the section below I use pretty much the same code:

```
<section id='a1' style="height:100%;background-color:white;">
    <div class="container"></div>
        <div id="learn"><a href="#">Learn More</a>
</section>
```

However this time the learn more box doesn't appear. What is it I am doing wrong? I have played around with `position: relative` without much luck.

TLDR: The learn more box should be at the bottom middle of the header and sections, it only appears in the header.

P.s I tried to strip down my code and css but didn't want to strip out any more as I believe its inclusion will highlight which options will / wont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
section {
    position: relative;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9uxGq/5/